# NodeJS - TypeORM cascade insert using QueryBuilder

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to upsert an object array with a many-to-many relation to a MySQL table(s) using TypeORM query builder. Had to use the builder because repository save doesn't support upserts.
Problem is, while save cascades nested objects, QueryBuilder doesn't seem to (and RelationalQueryBuilder doesn't support upserts on MySQL).

Anyone know how I can do both? I want to both update and cascade, on an array.

First object:

```
@Entity()
export class Product {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column({ type: 'bigint', unique: true })
shopifyId: number;

@Column('int')
shopId: number | null;

@Column('varchar')
name: string | null;

@Column('varchar')
productType: string | null;

@Column('timestamp', { default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
updated: Date | null;

@ManyToMany(type => ProductTag, productTag => productTag.products, {
    cascade: ['insert', 'update']
})
@JoinTable()
productTags: ProductTag[] | null;
```

}

Second object:

```
@Entity()
export class ProductTag {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column('varchar')
name: string | null;

@ManyToMany(type => Product, product => product.productTags)
products: Product[] | null;
```

}

Current upsert:

```
    getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .relation(Product, 'productTags')
    .insert()
    .into(Product)
    .values(products)
    .orUpdate({
        conflict_target: ['shopifyId'],
        overwrite: ['name', 'shopId', 'productType', 'updated']
    })
    .execute();
```

Thank you

Comment: Cascading is a schema level behavior. Are you talking about something else?

Comment: I'm referring to typeORM's "cascade" relation option, defined in the "product" model.
It's probably defined at schema level, but doesn't seem to work with the QueryBuilder insert method (works with the Repository save method)

Comment: You got a solution?

Comment: did you find the solution @ViniciusSpinellis ?